# Multiple wildcards in GNU Makefile Pattern

Tags: build, makefile, build-process, gnu-make

My filetree looks somewhat like this:

```
Makefile
src/foo/foo.c
src/bar/bar.c
build/bin/
build/libs/
```

Each sub-directory contains other files related to the source, so i want 
some structure. Since i have many *foos* and even more *bars*, i thought of a pattern rule:

```
PROGS=foo bar

all : $(PROGS)

% :: src/%/%.c
    @echo $@ $<
```

Unfortunately make does not recognize this as a valid pattern:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `foo', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

However, If I keep all files in just the *src/* directory, a single % works as expected:

```
% :: src/%.c
    @echo $@ $<

Output:
foo src/foo
bar src/bar
```

Is there a way to do this without giving up the structure?

Comment: You can use make functions to generate targets and prerequisites on the fly from your list of `PROGS` so that they are all explicit instead of trying to use a pattern rule like this. At its simplest something like `$(foreach p,$(PROGS),src/$p/%.c)` in the prerequisite of that target should "work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [vpath](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search):

```
PROGS=foo bar

all : $(PROGS)

% : %.c
    @echo $@ $<

vpath %.c src/foo src/bar
```

And if you want to put the binaries in `build/bin/`,

```
PROGS = build/bin/foo build/bin/bar

all : $(PROGS)

build/bin/% : %.c
    @echo $@ $<

vpath %.c src/foo src/bar
```